# Google Maps API Makers from JSON Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, google-maps-api-3

I have a php script that forms an array, and then echos as json - which an AJAX call picks it up. That part is working.

The PHP script outputs the following example:

```
[{"p": "123456","latlng": "52.012312,-.4213123"},{"p": "78910","latlng": "53.01,-.4128"}];
```

It needs to be in the format of `[123456,52.012312,-.4213123],[780910, 53.01,-.4123]`

Can somebody assist me in taking the current array, and using jquery to form a new array that fits the maps API requirements?

Maps Scripts:

```
function initialize() {
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
};

// Display a map on the page
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
map.setTilt(45);

// Multiple Markers
var markers = window.latlng;
//test markers
//= [
//    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856],
//      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052],
//      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507],
  //    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187]
 // ];

// Info Window Content (test content)
var infoWindowContent = [
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>London Eye</h3>' +
    '<p>The London Eye is a giant Ferris wheel situated on the banks of the River Thames. The entire structure is 135 metres (443 ft) tall and the wheel has a diameter of 120 metres (394 ft).</p>' +        '</div>'],
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>Palace of Westminster</h3>' +
    '<p>The Palace of Westminster is the meeting place of the House of Commons and the House of Lords, the two houses of the Parliament of the United Kingdom. Commonly known as the Houses of Parliament after its tenants.</p>' +
    '</div>']
];

// Display multiple markers on a map
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

// Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
function placemarker() {
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][0]
    });

    // Allow each marker to have an info window    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));

    // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
}
// Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed',     function(event) {
    this.setZoom(14);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
});
```

AJAX call/Jquery:

```
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "engine.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {req: 'latlng'},
            success: function(latlng){
            console.log("LATLNG:"+latlng);
            //var l = JSON.parse(latlng);
                var con = [];
                for(var i in latlng) {
                con.push([latlng[i][1],latlng[i][2]]);
                }
                window.latlng = con;
                placemarker();
                //var l = [];
                ////$.each(l, function(k, v) {
                //l.push([v.price, v.latlng]);
               // window.latlng = l;
                //});
            console.log(window.latlng);
            },
            error: function(){
            //alert(html);
            },
            complete: function(){
            }
        });
```

Currently there is no error or output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the array of objects to the desired format like this:

```js
var dataFromPhp = [{p: '123456',latlng: '52.012312,-.4213123'},{p: '78910',latlng: '53.01,-.4123'}];
var dataForGoogle = dataFromPhp.map(function (obj) { 
  return [obj.p].concat(obj.latlng.split(',')); 
})
document.write(dataForGoogle.join(' ** '));
```

Comment: I did this, but the map still appears blank.

Comment: I also get: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Weird, I don't get an exception when I run on Stack Overflow. Here is a fiddle that shows how a basic example would work to put points on a map: http://jsfiddle.net/xw5f1sgy/

Comment: I think I found the issue. The array output is exactly as follows:

Comment: [{"p:" "123456","latlng": "52.012312,-.4213123"},{"p" "78910","latlng": "53.01,-.4128"}];

Comment: When I change the code to this, it breaks the fiddle

Comment: The colon goes outside of the quotes so `"p:"` becomes `"p":`

Comment: Fixed the output. No changes to the map... [{"p" :  "123456","latlng": "52.012312,-.4213123"},{"p" : "78910","latlng": "53.01,-.4128"}];

Comment: If it's still not working you're going to have to send a link to a fiddle so I can see the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73444/discussion-between-pherris-and-user3259138).